# Ruby NATS simple publishing

Tags: ruby, message-queue

I'm learning NATS in Ruby and wanted to create a simple "cat" from stdin.  Either I get all the lines and the loop doesn't exit, or nothing gets sent.

```
!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "nats/client"

queue = ARGV.shift

NATS.start do
  STDIN.each_line do |line|
    puts "will send: #{line}"
    NATS.publish(queue, line)
  end

  NATS.stop
end

puts "... #{__LINE__}"
exit 0
```

And I run with:

```
# cat cat.rb | ./cat.rb myqueue
```

With NATS.stop enabled, nothing shows up on the queue, though it correctly shows each line that it will attempt to send, and the program exits:

```
# cat cat.rb | ./cat.rb myqueue
will send: #!/usr/bin/env ruby
will send: 
will send: require "nats/client"
will send: 
will send: queue = ARGV.shift
will send: 
will send: NATS.start do
will send:   STDIN.each_line do |line|
will send:     puts "will send: #{line}"
will send:     NATS.publish(queue, line)
will send:   end
will send: 
will send:   NATS.stop
will send: end
will send: 
will send: puts "... #{__LINE__}"
will send: exit 0
will send: 
... 16
#
```

And with NATS.stop commented out, all the lines are sent to the queue, but the program doesn't exit:

```
# cat cat.rb | ./cat.rb myqueue
will send: #!/usr/bin/env ruby
will send: 
will send: require "nats/client"
will send: 
will send: queue = ARGV.shift
will send: 
will send: NATS.start do
will send:   STDIN.each_line do |line|
will send:     puts "will send: #{line}"
will send:     NATS.publish(queue, line)
will send:   end
will send: 
will send:   # NATS.stop
will send: end
will send: 
will send: puts "... #{__LINE__}"
will send: exit 0
will send: 
<and program sits here>
```

What am I missing?  Isn't there something easier for just sending a message from Ruby that doesn't involve multi-threading issues?

Comment: What happens if you put `sleep 60` at the end of your program with `NATS.stop` enabled? Do the messages get delivered then?

Comment: Actually I think you need to call `NATS.flush` before you call `stop` to ensure processing of all messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your example you can give it a try at doing something like so that all lines are published and flushed to the server before stopping the event loop.

```
require 'nats/client'

$stdout.sync = true

NATS.start(servers: ["nats://127.0.0.1:4222"]) do |nats|
  STDIN.read.each_line do |line|
    nats.publish("hello", line)
  end
  nats.flush do
    nats.close
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, wallyqs, thank you.  With some tinkering, it seems I needed the instance variable "nats" in the loop and the nats.flush/nats.close combination.  Any other combination ended up with the behavior earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for the library `NATS.stop` seems to be very aggressive in that it disconnects immediately, without checking if there is still some processing left to do.

Therefore it seems calling `NATS.flush` before `NATS.stop` is the solution, because it should ensure all pending events are processed before closing the connection:

```
NATS.start do
  ...do your messaging...

  NATS.flush  # Ensure processing of pending messages    
  NATS.stop   # Immidiate exit
end
```

Comment: Thank you for that, however the behavior is completely unchanged.  With NATS.stop commented: I get the messages delivered (I'm listening with nats-sub in a different window); With NATS.stop in place, no messages are delivered, though it claims they will be sent.  This is all with the NATS.flush in place as recommended.

Comment: Ok. Really strange. Don't know what's going on then :( Would need to debug it more thoroughly in this case.

Comment: Perhaps raise and issue on github and see if you get help there, then post the solution here.